# How to predict stress magnitudes due to moisture changes?

Tags: moisture

There's lots of published data that characterize dimensional changes to wood as its moisture content changes. But in all of those publications, they seem to use a free-standing piece of wood.

But are there any datasets showing how *much force* is generated when a piece of wood cannot freely expand/contract in response to that various factors known to result in dimensional changes?

This question is inspired by several DIY projects I've worked on. For those projects I wanted to know how I could nail / glue / screw / etc. certain pieces of wood to other, more dimensionally stable materials, in order to limit the wood's dimensional changes. But the question I'm asking here is a little more academic.

Comment: You will probably not find this data related to woodworking. The only people who would care to this degree are structural engineers who are working with engineered wood products. That is, wood varies so much, even within the same species and the same chunk of timber, that most woodworkers just go by feel and experience. But if you want to use wood to make large architectural structures you'll need some data on how this variable product can be made more uniform.

Comment: At architectural scale wood is not actually constricted in this way.  Structural connectors allow enough space for the relatively minor expansion that occur across width and depth of timber framing.  Any force from restriction in either the wood or any connecting collar would be well within the ability of the wood to compress within its constraints or the collar to resist without any significant structural denigration.  Also note that composite wood framing materials such as plywood or laminate beams are already being restrained from expansion/contraction by the glue matrix.

Comment: *"For those projects I wanted to know how I could nail / glue / screw / etc. certain pieces of wood to other, more dimensionally stable materials, in order to limit the wood's dimensional changes. "* Yeah, uh, don't do that :-) What should be done instead is working within the material's needs. Because the amount of force generated by expanding wood can be sizeable, and it's repeated, so the effect is cumulative — a tabletop poorly attached to its leg assembly can shear a couple off screw heads. If the fasteners are good, and numerous, it's the wood that gives way (you get cracks or warping).

Comment: @Ashlar, I'm speaking about the "composites" that some companies make out of much smaller pieces, where there is very little movement in particular directions because it has been combined in such a way to minimize that movement. Small dimensions built-up into larger ones with specific alignment, and joinery that relies less on tight mating but rather mechanical fasteners -- or some that allow for movement, and others that are tight. These are people that would have measured strain on various axes.

Comment: May as well tack on a possible duplicate https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/12808/5572

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is difficult to quantify and will be incredibly narrow if it should ever become available.  too many variables to account for to be useful for the average woodworker.

Answer (score -1):

If you think about wood at the cellular level as long cylinders filled with cellulose and water and some other stuff, with these cylinders arranged side-by-side to form rings, you could probably approximate the stresses in different directions by considering hydrodynamic pressure on the lateral walls of a single cylinder and relating it to the vapor pressure at the ends (i.e., the end grain).  Stress is a tensor so the force would depend on both the orientation of a particular cross-section and its area, integrated over some surface.  My physics is rusty but that's the best I can do off the cuff.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Other than the problem of only partial water content (which I'm sure throws a spanner in the works right at the get-go) I presume cylinder diameter is critical to any calculations.......

Comment: Thanks.  Yep, this type of calculation would only provide an upper bound, and you're right that for a more exact calculation, cylinder diameter would be critical since the cellular walls also resist the pressure.